# Dockerfile: /bin/sh: 1: apt-get: not found

Tags: python, dockerfile

When building a Docker file, I get the error

```
"/bin/sh: 1: apt-get: not found"
```

docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV PATH="/env/bin/activate"
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y

WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "manage.py"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are setting the `PATH` to `/env/bin/activate` and that is then the only place where `apt-get` is searched for. There is no need to activate a virtual env inside the container, just get rid of that line. `pip` can install the packages in `requirements.txt` to the "system" Python without issues.
2. You cannot layer 2 images like you are attempting to do, with multiple FROM statements. Just use `FROM python:3.8` and drop the ubuntu. Multiple `FROM` statements are used in multi-stage builds where you have intermediate images which produce artifacts that are copied to the final image.

So just do:

```
FROM python:3.8
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py"]
```

.. although why you would put Python code in /var/www/html beats me. Probably you don't.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I'm just starting to teach docker, so I don't understand what to refer to, and the videos on YouTube are uninformative. And I put this file there because I want to run python (django) on the nginx web server. Although I don't know if it will work or if it is possible. I would be grateful if you answer this question.

Comment: Setting up Django + nginx in Docker is way beyond the scope of the question. In a container pattern you want to run Django, nginx and your DB all in separate containers. See for example: https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/